# Fetch website data using curl in php

Tags: php, curl

I am  getting  website data using curl in php but issue is that I am not able to get desired website data .It only showing data of home page.

```
<?php 
$url="http://fdating.com/";
function getHTML($url,$timeout)
{
   $ch = curl_init($url); // initialize curl with given url
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]); // set  useragent
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // write the      response to a variable
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // follow redirects if any
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout); // max. seconds to execute
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1); // stop when it encounters an error
   return @curl_exec($ch);
}
$resp=getHTML($url,200);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($resp);
$arr = json_decode( json_encode($xml) , 1);
print_r($arr);

?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by desired website?

Comment: You will need [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/page/2/) like app for your purpose you are describing here, `cURL` is for specific purposes

Comment: are you want to fetch data of complete site?

Comment: Deep kakkar , yes I want to fetch complete web site data  of  any site but my code is only working  for some sites

Comment: You might want to fetch all the `URL's` from the website `sitemap.xml` and then, go through each `url` provided from first fetch.